# Generalized Low-Rank Models in a Regression Format

Tags: regression, pca, modeling, dimensionality-reduction

I've been using principle component regression (PCR) to model data, and was interested in using generalized low rank models (GLRM) in its place. Using PCR, I am able to easily get the coefficients for regression. However, I am confused on how to do this using the archetypes in GLRM. In GLRMs, the "X" and "Y" matrix multiply to have the same dimensions of the original design matrix, where as in PCR we take the first r many components of the eigenmatrix and use this to get a lower dimension representation in the r-many principle components.

Am I missing a connection to have a lower rank representation of the design matrix that I can then estimate coefficients on in a regression setting? Are there any papers/packages that already do this? So far I have been coding in R and investigating the h2o package.